# Xubuntu 13.10: Only four levels of brightness?

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, video, brightness

Why do I have only four levels of brightness on my Dell Inspiron laptop, selectable by Fn+ArrowDown/Up? In Linux Mint Mate, I have 7 or 8, and so I have under Windows, on the same machine? This is annoying...

Comment: Please add some information about your graphic card and driver ;)

Comment: How do I find out what driver I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Different video drivers. Once you have determined what driver is used by Mint Mate, use that driver with Xubuntu.

Comment: What's strange is that on the login screen of Xubuntu, I have my 8 levels of brightness, selectable via Fn+ArrowUp/Down! Only after the login, this is reduced to 4 levels. So the problem should not be the driver, but a configuration I cannot find.